# Como acceder a una propiedad de una clase desde un array

Tags: java, array, java-swing

estoy almacenando los datos de un pequeño formulario de un JFrame en un arreglo creado a partir de una clase y sus propiedades.Comparo el número que se ingresó en el formulario con el número que el usuario está buscando. Pero solo muestra el resultado del último Estudiante agregado, los que se agregan despues no lo muestra. La informacion del estudiante se guarda en el arreglo sin problema.

```
//boton para añadir datos al arreglo
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        if(counter< studentList.length){
        String code= txtcode.getText();
        String name= txtname.getText();
        String lastname= txtlastname.getText();
        String rh = comborh.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int age= Integer.parseInt(txtage.getText());

        //the object is created
        Student objStudent = new Student();

        objStudent.setCode(code);
        objStudent.setName(name);
        objStudent.setLastname(lastname);
        objStudent.setAge(age);
        objStudent.setRH(rh);

        studentList[counter] = objStudent;
        counter++;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"n° "+ counter+ " Students.");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } 



//Boton para realizar la busqueda
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String code= txtcode.getText();   
    String name= txtname.getText();
    String search= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"search by code");

    for (int i = 0; i<=studentList.length;i++){
        if ((search).equals(code)){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"code with the name of: "+name);
        }   
    }                                         
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se ingresa el codigo con el `showInputDialog`, los TextField.getText() del método 'buscar' están de más. Tendrías que cambiar esta parte:

```
 if (studentList[i].getCode() == Integer.parseInt(search)){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"code with the name of: "+ studentList[i].getNombre());
 }
```

Sino estarías mostrando siempre el nombre que está escrito en el el TextField al momento de llamar al método.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
studentList[posicion].getCode();
studentList[posicion].getName();
```

Porque studentList es un arreglo de la clase Student.

Te he de recomendar para el caso que presentas, mejor el uso de la clase List.